# scintilla not recognizing newlines

Tags: c++, newline, scintilla

I'm trying to write my own Lexer for Scintilla. So far, I've only added single-line comment coloring. It works, but the problem is, the coloring never ends even after a new line like it is supposed to. Debugging the program, I've found out that the Match() member function belonging to the StyleContext class never recognizes newline characters. Why is it so? What can I do to fix this? Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
     case SCE_DD_COMMENT:
        if (scCTX.Match('\n') || scCTX.Match('\r')) {
           scCTX.Forward();
           scCTX.ForwardSetState(SCE_DD_DEFAULT);
        }
     break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 case SCE_DD_COMMENT:
    if (scCTX.ch('\n') || scCTX.ch('\r')) {
       scCTX.SetState(SCE_DD_DEFAULT);
    }
 break;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, direct comparison doesn't seem to work either as this is how Match() is implemented anyway.

Comment: There could be something missing or overriding this node. Try to identify the possible code other than this.

Comment: I've figured it out. There was an extra call to Forward() somewhere in my code which kept setting the ch variable to default. Silly me! :) Thanks for your help!